# How to operate objects parametrized with the Nothing type

Tags: scala, types

I worked with `TypeTag`s and noticed very strange scala compiler behaviour

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

def accept[T](arg : TypeTag[T]) = true
def pass[T](arg : TypeTag[T]) : TypeTag[T] = arg

val ntt = implicitly[TypeTag[Nothing]]

accept(ntt)
pass(ntt)
```

returns error:

```
NastyNothing.scala:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Nothing]
 required: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T]
Note: Nothing <: T, but trait TypeTag is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: T`. (SLS 3.2.10)
  pass(ntt)
       ^
```

I could accept `TypeTag` of `Nothing` but could not pass it around. Moreover it fails similar with any object parametrized by the `Nothing` type.

```
final case class Hold[T]()

def accept[T](arg : Hold[T]) = true
def pass[T](arg : Hold[T]) : Hold[T] = arg

val hn = Hold[Nothing]()

accept(hn)
pass(hn)
```

return the same error:

```
NastyNothing.scala:24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : TestHolder.Hold[Nothing]
 required: TestHolder.Hold[T]
Note: Nothing <: T, but class Hold is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
  pass(hn)
       ^
```

What is proper way to handle `Nothing`-parametrized objects? How should the `pass` method be redefined to process `TypeTag[Nothing]` correctly?

Comment: Which Scala version are you compiling against?

Comment: Scala compiler version 2.11.11-20160304-000000-1706a37eb8 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL

Comment: Scala compiler version 2.12.4-20171010-223542-c2a5883 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.

Comment: Compiles for me with both Scala versions

Comment: Do the versions matches exactly? I'm mystified in that case. I specially extracted example to separate small file to get rid of interference

Comment: if you explicitly specify the type parameter it works: `accept[Nothing](hn)`. Seems like a compiler bug otherwise.